# How I delete multiple records with react, php and MySQL?

Tags: php, reactjs, foreach, sql-delete

REACT FILE: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CN6F.png) PHP FILE[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wXVb.png)When I don't put the foreach I just delete the first item of the array, with the foreach I can't delete any item, and the var_dump appears: Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in C:\ wamp64\www\juniortest\delete.php on line *13*

I have to delete multiple cards that have checkboxes, with only one delete button, without the forEach of the php file I can only delete the first item in the array, when I put the foreach I can't delete any, and there is a Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in C:\wamp64\www\juniortest\delete.php on line *13* in the php file, but I don't know how I fix that, and I delete more than one at the same time

Comment: Your error states that variable you are trying to iterate (for each loop) is a null.
Instead of how do you delete check why you have a null variable (assuming you expect they are multiple db records).

Posting some piece of code would also provide more insight of the problem in hand.

Comment: You could delete multiple records with a where statement like DELETE FROM posts WHERE id IN ([1,2,3,4])

Comment: but I don't understand why it's null, because without the foreach I can delete it by receiving that variable

Comment: I added the images of the react and php file

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75298838/edit) to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).